# MacOS + Visual Studio Code: add a folder to a workspace by path

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to inspect the code in a module found in a subfolder of `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/*`.

The trouble is that Visual Studio Code only gives me the system `finder` view, to navigate to the folder, and I'm not quite sure how to get to the root to even *find* `/usr`.

- typing the path in the `search` bar doesn't help
- navigating to `Macintosh HD` and or `Volumes` still doesn't show me `/usr` or other common Linux folders located on the root filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method should work in any app that uses the standard file dialogs:

1. In the Finder open a new window
2. Type Command-Shift-G or select `Go to Folder…` from the Finder’s `Go` menu
3. Enter your path, e.g. `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages`
4. You now have a Finder window showing the (parent) folder of where you want to explore
5. In VSCode type Command+O or select `Open…` from the `File` menu
6. A standard file dialog will open
7. Click on a folder icon in your *Finder* window, this can be an icon in the window itself or the one in the window’s title bar, and drag and drop it onto the standard file dialog.
8. The dialog will switch to show the dropped folder
9. Continue navigating as usual

Comment: I _knew_ it was one of Apple's super-secret key-combos . Thanks!